# VM website connection

Tags: connection, virtual-machine, local

I have a website running on a VM in my machine it's a website that displays what the sonos is playing. The sites ip is 127.0.0.1:5000 and the VM is in bridged adapter mode however I am not able to connect to this site on my host machine.
Not sure how to progress here i've disabled the firewall and still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to overcome this issue:

1. Check the Internet connection is VM and Check the IP address associated with Bridge Network adapter not the loopback IP address (lo/loopback IP address is: `127.0.0.1`)
2. Use this IP address along with port in the Host machine.
3. In `Advanced Network setting` of virtual machine, select `Allow All` for `Promiscuous Mode`.

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 is localhost and your webpage/website is running inside VM. In simple terms, it's like calling self on host instead of pointing to VM

Since you have bridge network, your VM should have some IP, 
1. Check your web server/program is listening on both public IP preferably *
2. Check firewall 
3. Access from host machine via this new IP which you received from bridge network